# Learning PLC programming

Tags: plc

How do I learn PLC programming? Would it differ greatly for different brands of PLCs? Is ladder programming the same as PLC programming?

Answer (score 63):

I did a lot of PLC programming, and now do quite a bit of .NET programming.  It's very dangerous to make the switch either way, because a lot of the skills that you think should be transferrable (patterns and such) lead you very far astray.

The biggest difference that I tell people is that PC program code should be written as if other programmers are the audience, but PLC programs (ladder logic) must be written as if maintenance people are the audience.  Maintainance in most facilities (particularly manufacturing) frequently connect directly to PLCs and in online mode they can watch the code execute graphically to figure out what's wrong.

For instance, if an output isn't turning on, they'll type the output electrical device ID into the find function of the programming software, find that output coil, and start tracing back from there looking for issues.  One of the frequent mistakes that some PLC programmers make is to "map" their I/O into a structure (in PLCs, these are called user-defined types), and they use a copy instruction to move all the inputs or outputs over to the structure at once.  Makes sense from a PC programming perspective, but it makes the maintenance person want to kill you.  Typically the programming software provides a cross reference feature where they can specify that output coil, and it will tell them everywhere in the program that it's used.  If you use a copy instruction to move 10 words of I/O into a 10 word data structure, he's got to sit there and count bits to figure out which bit in the source of the copy maps to which bit on the destination side of the copy.  True, comments can help, but there's a problem with that too... PLCs store the whole program and allow you to upload the program from it in an emergency if you need to troubleshoot and you don't have a copy of the original program.  The problem is that for space reasons, the PLC doesn't store the comments.  So if the line is down, it's costing $5000 per minute in downtime, and a guy runs out there with a laptop, he might have to do a quick upload without comments and try to troubleshoot it.  Having those copy instructions in there, wasting 10 minutes of his time, just cost the company $50,000 in downtime.  These are the things you have to be aware of when writing PLC programs.

Some other tips: some PLCs have support for FOR loops.  **Never** use them.  For the same reason above, they make the code very difficult to troubleshoot for a maintenance person.  This is because if you have one piece of code in the PLC that gets scanned more than once per scan (like the contents of a loop), then when you go into online debugging mode, the software can't show you the values for each of 10 loops that executed this scan, so you really have no idea what value you're looking at.  Then you have to write all this tricky code to pull the loop values for a specific loop index out into some other tags (variables) that you can monitor.  That's just one more impedance to fixing the problem in an emergency.  Using a subroutine more than once per scan suffers from the same problem.

Indirect addressing (what we would call Arrays) are very difficult for maintenance people to understand.  It's generally OK to use them when you're dealing with recipe management (storing and retrieving values for how to build your part) but you should try to stay away from it in the control part of the program.

In PC programming, of course we seek to re-use code as much as possible. However, in PLCs and control systems, downtime is extremely expensive, and hardware is expensive.  Memory is cheap, and actually PLC programmers are cheap.  Therefore, it's expected that if you have 10 identical things on your machine (like conveyor drives or something) that you will have 10 different files (subroutines), one for each drive, and each drive will have its own variables associated with them: e.g. Drive1_Run, Drive2_Run, Drive3_Run, etc.  This is going to feel very "wrong" to you when you come from a PC programming background, but this is all because of the points I've made above.  When you're in a downtime situation, and someone says that Drive 3 isn't working, you crack open the laptop, go to the file for Drive 3 and you look at the Run output rung.  You start troubleshooting from there, while the program is executing.  There's no breakpoints (the program never stops).

Good luck on your endeavors.  I wrote up some more [insights from my years of programming PLCs](http://www.contactandcoil.com/), if you want to check them out.

Comment: Scott, I have been the maintenance guy, and the guy writing the PLC programs (still am!), and now I have dabbled a bit in writing some .NET with C#, and I can tell you that you are bang on the money with all that you have said above! Great answer.

Comment: Helpful side note: the part on comments not being stored in PLC memory might not be as much of an issue 8 years after this answer was posted...Many newer PLC's now store program and tag comments in memory with the project file.

Answer (score 18):

You can learn PLC programming from various sources on the internet, one of which is [this(wikibooks)](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Introductory_PLC_Programming) or [this](http://www.eod.gvsu.edu/~jackh/books/plcs/pdf/plcbook5_0.pdf)

The program that you write will be pretty much the same across different brands of PLCs for LLDs (Ladder Logic Diagrams) unless you use PLC specific functions. But there will be much more differences if you use some language like IL (Instruction List). But once you have written the program, the format of storage and execution differs widely across brands

Ladder logic is one of the 5 programming languages for PLC, the others being FBD (Function block diagram),  ST (Structured text, similar to the Pascal programming language), IL (Instruction list, similar to assembly language) and SFC (Sequential function chart). These are just various representations of the programming language, various flavours if you will. But usually, a given brand supports only one of these. In USA, LLDs are widely used, while in Europe, ILs are more popular.

Answer (score 14):

Ladder, often call LD is one of several language styles defined in ISO 61131 automation programming standard. Others are SFC (sequential flow chart), FBD (functional block diagram), ST (structured text), and IL (instruction list). IL is similar to assembler and very few people use it. ST is a text based programming much like early versions of BASIC. It is not often used either. LD is designed to resemble relay contacts off an electrical control panel (which many PLC replaced). FBD looks more like a circuit diagram. SFC is basically a flow chart.

Some PLC support all, other only some, or even one. While LD is the most common, FBD and SFC are gain popularity.

Different brands do use slightly different programming languages. They are usually similar enough that once you understand one brand, you can work with any of them, but you cannot directly take code from one PLC and using on another brand.

Comment: LD is actually very common in North America, but in my experience is rarely used, and often looked down on, by people in, say, Europe.  I believe this is because in Europe a maintenance person doesn't go online with a PLC - they call the engineering department for that, but in North America maintenance will go online for troubleshooting, will make changes, and in some cases do a lot of the programming work.  The circuit-like LD is just better suited to this culture.

Comment: @Scott: "I believe this is because in Europe a maintenance person doesn't go online with a PLC" - I would disagree with that. I spent years doing precisely that, even writing programs from scratch, all in my role as electrical maintenance.

Answer (score 13):

The answers given so far are pretty on target. One thing I found that PLCs have a split personality when it comes to their langauges and setup. Their core design is to give the electrical guys a flexible means of setting up control logic for their overall design. PLCs are basically a bunch of input and a bunch of outputs and how they are connected is controlled by the software you load into the device.

One of the emphasis of the languages that are used for PLCs is that they are accessible to people coming from an electrical background. So the idioms and structures seem counter intuitive for a person used to high level languages or even assembly languages. Ladder Logic for example is very accessible for electrical folks.

However in recent years PLCs have been supporting a multitude of languages for maximum flexibility. However in my opinion the handful of PLCs I worked are very lacking in terms of being a programming environment. Simple things like assigning variable names to memory location are often not designed into the language being used. The ones that are easy to work are often not the most cost effective for the job.

Despite these handicaps they are excellent for simplifying complex electrical systems. If you are working with others on a project, you will find that your knowledge of programming will help the project solve thorny programs. I was able to take a 100 rung ladder logic program and rewrite it into a third of the rungs. Once I was able to learn the ladder logic language I was able implement various optimizations that reduced the complexity of the program.

One tip is that you will need to learn about latching. Sometimes you will need to store or hold some output and unless you have a latch it the result will disappear the next cycle. Once you understand the issue it become clear but at first it was a great source of frustration for me.

Answer (score 7):

PLC programming should be viewed as implementation activity of PLC software engineering output, unless you are using PLC as purely part of alternative components to mechanical or electrical solutions.

With this as basis, PLC programming environment is typically IEC61131 driven, gauranteed cycle time, "pre-emptive" realtime, no need to handle realtime OS related issues, continuous code scanning, non-program-pointer, different concept from typical computer task spawning kind of multi-tasking. Code execution is naturally atomic, no need to use monitors between tasks.

Each of the languages has its closeness to how conceivable is your code to the logic model you want to implement.

1. Ladder has its basic concept on electrical power flow interlocking style. Code resolution within single network is either horizontal or vertical scanning (your can find resource on this topic from manufacturer or other sites). If your code has single scan resolution nature and is within one network, some unconceivable behavior can be due to scanning type (important to remember that ladder is only emulation of electrical circuit, it is still sequential in execution).
2. FBD or function block diagram was electronic signal flow but today can be data flow depending on type of PLC. FBD shows clearer execution sequence quite similar to horizontal scanning ladder in scanning sequence. Today, FBD is typically used as container for object function blocks, although dependency implementation and visual similarity to process model is dependent on PLC type.
3. Literal is very similar to BASIC, but syntax only; execution is still scan-through. Literal language is good for mathematical calculation. For high level implementation, methods or derivation of attributes within object can be easier using Literal. State machine programming using English-like state representation or constants makes program very readable.
4. Statement list looks similar to assembly mnemonics but again execution is still scan-through and not program pointer. It is strong in bit operation and parenthesis-styled discrete logics. It can be a very efficient language to use with proper structuring and commenting.
5. SFC or sequential flow chart is a complementary language for sequence implementation. SFC has inherent rules on action block activation, state transitions, parellel sequence activation and merging. However, complex exception branching or concurrent action management can make implementation complicated and flow chart difficult to read.

PLC system management on IO handling, communication, hot-standby is hardware configuration effort, and is product dependent. Generally, can be treated separately from software engineering. However, data related to PLC system management are of "located" (independent data addressing area) type, good data modeling approach in software engineering can help in manageability of system data.

Comment: I am afraid this is my second downvote for this user, but the description given obfuscates and complicates the task. Software engineering principles used for "regular" software does not really apply to PLC/PAC programming in general. Think of the difference between writing a client application for a desktop and writing a hard realtime system to control a cars engine. Totally different approaches are used, techniques appropriate to the application.

Answer (score 5):

The [Online PLC Simulator](http://www.plcsimulator.net/) may be useful.

Answer (score 3):

You can use **Structured Text (ST)** which consists of a series of instructions which, as determined in high level languages, ("IF..THEN..ELSE") or in loops (WHILE..DO) can be executed.

I find it better than Ladder as it is close to standard programming language.

Answer (score 1):

I had a little of PLC programming on University. It seemed to me, to be a one level lower than assembly, but device we were using wasn't the newest one.

I belive you need to have a PLC driver, but I would first look for simulators and read more about it before buying.

Comment: I disagree with your "one level lower than assembly" idea.  If you look at the OPcodes generated by the ladder logic, that looks exactly like Assembly language (XIC, etc.).  In IEC-61131-3 lingo, that's "Instruction List" (IL).  Ladder logic is a visual language with similarities to Function Block Diagram, which is definitely a higher level than Assembly (specifically because it's more declarative than imperative).

Answer (score 1):

Allen-Bradley has a free dos based software PLC, specifically for training.  You can probably find it if you go to their site, or Google it.   It's used to teach PLC programming in schools.

Answer (score 1):

For a beginner trying to learn ladder logic, the best way is to attend free online training at http://plcs.net

Answer (score -3):

PLC is the term used for the devices that use ladder logic.  The devices that are programmed in more typical programming languages are generally called microcontrollers.  However, there are some of us that on occasion lump them all under the PLC name.  :-)  Not sure how much ladder logic varies, but microcontroller code can vary significantly.